# Member function returning a static variable

Tags: c++, methods, static

Should a member function that returns a `static` member variable also be `static`?

For instance:

```
struct T {
   static int i;
   static int getNumber() {
       return i;
   }
};
```

Should `getNumber` be `static` or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, yes.

If the variable doesn't have any per-instance state, then what possible per-instance logic could the function perform on it before returning it?

Comment: @Ben, I was thinking of something else at the time I made the comment (i.e. hokey way of keeping track of count of instances)... anyways - removed the dodgy comment...

Comment: @Nim: I was wondering whether someone might bring up something like that. You're not going mad. But it's highly unlikely that you'd ever want to do that in a simple getter.

Answer (score 3):

It's not compulsory.  you can write a member function that returns a static variable.  You cannot go the other way around (write a static function which returns an instance variable).

As an example of a case where you may want to return a static member, imagine a circumstance where the class holds a state variable and based on the state you would return one of the static values.  Not that this is good design, but its not completely inconceivable